# workflow to show the amount of tree columns in one column

Tags: workflow, calculated-column

I have a list with tree columns that get year,month, day from user and I need to show the full date in another column.
For example, if an user type 2 in day field, September in month field and 2004 in year field the system should automatically write "2september2004" in another column.

How can i do it? Is it possible to do this with a calculated column?

Comment: You know you could use a date time column, right?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is possible with the Calculated Formula **TEXT()**

See: https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

for all Functions, take some time to read them all and see which one are of interest